# Objective C pointers to primitive types

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, primitive

I came from a java background and I'm trying to figure out if translating the following piece of java code:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int[] someArray;
    //+....other instance variables

    public SomeClass(int arraySize) {
        this.someArray = new int[arraySize];
        //some other initialization
    }
}
```

could be safely translated to Objective C as follows:

```
@implementation SomeClass
{
    int *_myArray;
    //some other private fields...
}

-(instancetype)initWithArraySize:(int)arraySize
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        int newArray[arraySize];
        _myArray = newArray;
        //some other initializations
    }
    return self;
}
}
```

I'm obviously aware of NSArray and NSNumber boxing but the above code sounds cleaner and more efficient, specially that my app will need at some cases to hold thousands of references to SomeClass. At the same time I'm not sure if primitive pointers are safe to use with ARC and whether they could cause leaks.

I've tried the following dummy test to see if things would work as expected:

```
@implementation SomeClassTests
{
    int *_myArray;
    //some other private fields...
}

- (void)testExample {
    int array[] = {4, 2, 1, 0};
    _myArray = array;

    [self changeArray:_myArray];
    XCTAssertEqual(_myArray[0], -1);
    XCTAssertEqual(_myArray[1], -1);
    XCTAssertEqual(_myArray[2], 1);
}

-(void)changeArray:(int *)array
{
    array[1] = -1;
    array[0] = -1;
}
}
```

The test passed, but I'm still not feeling really confident.

Any thoughts guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation will lead to serious errors as you allocate `newArray` on the stack and pass a pointer to the instance variable `someArray`, however once that method returns the stack will be recovered, making the `someArray` a dangling pointer.

It's more normal in Objective-C to use an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` objects for this.  If you want to create an array that can be added to after initialization,  and otherwise modified, then use an `NSMutableArray`:

```
@implementation SomeClass
{
    NSMutableArray *_someArray;
}

-(instancetype)initWithArraySize:(int)arraySize
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        _someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:arraySize];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: what if I use a heap allocation (_myArray = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int));) would that still result in a dangling pointer after initialization? I'm trying to reduce the memory footprint by avoiding NSMutableArray and NSNumber. I need to instantiate thousands of instances to SomeClass

Comment: @ALTN No, that's fine, and would be more C than Objective-C, however, given Objective-C provides collection classes for that purpose.  Using `malloc()` is perfectly legal, but don't forget to call `free()` in your `dealloc` method override!

Answer (score 1):

In Java code sample you allocate memory in Heap, but in Objective C code sample you allocate memory in Stack.

Here is variant with allocation in Heap:

```
-(instancetype)initWithArraySize:(int)arraySize
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        _myArray = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int));
        //some other initializations
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    if (_myArray != NULL) {
        free(_myArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: "but in Objective C code you allocate memory in Stack".  That isn't true.

Comment: @trojanfoe, where this array is initialized: `int newArray[arraySize];` ?

Comment: On the stack.  But the statement that all memory is allocated on the stack is not true.

Comment: when i said "in Objective C code" I mean specific code, that was provided by author. I will try to make it more clear.

Comment: @Visput, thanks for the clarification. Would you recommend the heap or the stack allocation?

Comment: @ALTN If you want exact analogue of java code, then you need use heap. Also it's better to use heap for huge arrays. For small arrays heap also can be used, but on stack it will work little faster. In general for flexibility I will recommend to use heap.